# selected value in dropdown list does not work Angular

Tags: angular, select

I want to use the selected value from dropdown list in my component class.
When a value is selected from drop down I store this value using ngModel but it does not work, also tried another approach i.e. I triggered an event function and passed the selected value as a parameter but this approach also does not work.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedControl" class="form-control" (click)="onSelection($event)">
          <option *ngFor="let control of controlArray; let i=index" 
          [value]="control">{{controlArray[i].name}}</option>                                              
</select>
```

When I output the selected value on console, it does not show, here is the component class code:

```
onSelection(control){  
    console.log(typeof(control))
    console.log(control.target.value)
  }
```

Please help.

Comment: You never log the selected value. You log the event ($event) passed to the method. Don't pass the event to the method, and simply log  `this.selectedControl`, since that's what is bound with ngModel. Also, the event should not be (click), but (change).

Comment: I also tried this solution before, but by logging this.selectedControl "[object Object]" displays on output rather than the selected value.

Comment: You probably need to bind to `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]`, since the native attribute only uses strings.

Comment: it's normal to show `[object object]` , because you are giving an object ( `control` ) as a value  of your `option`s , you can change the `[value]="control"`  to `[value]="control.value"` if u want to get it's value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `change` event, not `click`:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedControl" class="form-control" (change)="onSelection()">
  <option *ngFor="let control of controlArray; let i=index"
          [ngValue]="control">{{controlArray[i].name}}</option>
</select>
```

Also you should check the `selectedControl` for the currently selected value.

```
onSelection(){
  console.log(this.selectedControl)
}
```

Last thing - you should put there a scalar value if you want to do it like this or use `ngValue` instead.

Comment: I am not much clear conceptually, would you please refer some data links on this concept. –

Comment: What exactly do you mean? click vs change event? or ngValue?

Comment: Well if you use `[value]`, you will basically fill the value attribute of option element with some value. The value must be scalar (string, number, etc), you can not use object for this, otherwise you will get `[object Object]` as a response or something similar. If you want to use object, `[ngValue]` will overcome this issue automatically.